Riotous Long Island
In The Great Gatsby (1925), F. Scott Fitzgerald described Long Island as “that slender riotous island.”
Slender is understandable and OK, it’s about the shape. But what about riotous? Did he simply mean “rich in green plants”? Or there’re some overtones? Or something entirely different?

The primary sense of riotous applies to humans / human behaviour. Derived senses could apply to a tangle of plants, as you imply, or metonymically to an area where riotous behaviour is/was common (as here).

Metaphoric "rampant verdant vegetation" isn't likely in the cited context. It's OED definition #2 (1389–) Of life, conduct, etc.: extravagant, unrestrained, esp. marked by excessive revelry; wanton, dissolute.

riotous has nothing to do with green plants, I'm not sure where you got that from.
[dictionary.com] has the following definition:

given to or marked by unrestrained revelry; loose; wanton:
riotous living.

In the time this book takes place (the early 20th century), Long Island was not very developed. Much of it was farmland, but the shore towns had lots of mansions of rich families from New York. They were known for hosting extravagant parties attended by the rich and famous. That's what made it "riotous".
While much of the farmland has since been replaced by suburbs in the post-WWII era, remnants of this time can still be found in areas like the Hamptons. Many celebrities have estates there. And the Fire Island portion is well known as a gay retreat.

I got that from a translation that made me doubt. But I found another translation, and also incorrect, which made me doubt even more. Your answer is comprehensive and valuable.

There is another sense "having a vivid, varied appearance", so a garden full of colorful flowers might be described as riotous.

But the most common senses derive obviously from "riot".

OED definition #6: (1573–) Of plant growth, branches, etc.: overgrowing, luxuriant; exuberant. Frequently in figurative contexts.
